# how to generate thumbnail of video from http URL without download video in android?

Tags: android

I want to generate thumbnail of video from the URL without download the video.I have tried the below code but it not works for me ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

Comment: `createVideoThumbnail()` is for a file; you do not have a file. There is nothing built into Android to handle your request, and I would not be surprised if it is impossible in general. If you control the server, have the server serve a thumbnail via a related URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can get thumbnail with out downloading the video.

```
          public static Bitmap retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)
                throws Throwable
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
            try
            {
                mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                    mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath, new HashMap<String, String>());
                    else
                        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
             //   mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
                bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new Throwable(
                        "Exception in retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)"
                                + e.getMessage());

            }
            finally
            {
                if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null)
                {
                    mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
                }
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
```

Comment: @ user1682446 , how can i attcah an ImageView to a thumbnail , i tried to replace it with mediaMetadataRetriever but it didn't work